# Не отображать цифры при вводе пароля в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, password

Если использовать `EditText` атрибутом  `android:inputType="numberPassword"`, то при вводе пароля, на секунду цифры видны, а затем маскируются. Как сделать так, чтобы они сразу маскировались и не отображались?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Никто о такой проблеме не пишет. Это вы на телефоне проверяли? Может это проблема эмулятора андроида? С другой стороны если кто то подсматривает то все равно могут увидеть что вы набираете на клавиатуре.

Comment: Может просто эта проблема никого не волнует, для нас это важно. На разных физических устройствах проверял.

Comment: Хм. Как я понял это из за того что пользователи очень часто ошибаются при вводе пароля и так они могут проверять что вводят.
В ответе на аналогичный вопрос на английском, пишут делать поле с собственной функцией обработчиком ввода
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268004/how-to-hide-the-letters-of-a-password-while-typing

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перехватывайте вводимые символы, сохраняйте в переменную (например) а в EditTex сетите *

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.